# Prepend return type with slash for constructor

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpstorm

Is there a specific reason that PhpStorm prepends the return type of a constructor with a slash?

```
class MyTest
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return \MyTest
     **/
    public function __construct(){}
}
```

Does it have a special meaning within PHPDoc itself? Or some specific IDE functionality?

Comment: This *should* no longer be the issue with v4 (at very least when updating existing PHPDoc comment block): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9997

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically means that `MyTest` resides in the global [`namespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Right, I never used namespaces within PHP guess that is why I didn't know that notation. Cheers mate.